# check if the index exists in elasticsearch or not using sparkR without using "elastic" package

Tags: elasticsearch, sparkr

I require function similar to R function index_exists() in sparkR to check whether any index is exists or not in elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

```
    library(httr)
    Index_Exists <- function(index_name,doc_type,es_IP)
    {
      Home_tl =  HEAD('es_IP/index_name/mapping/doc_type')
      return(Home_tl$status)
    }


# Index_Exists() function returns the status if it is 200 then index exists if it is 404 then index doesn't exists 

if(Index_Exists(input_index,doctype,es_IP)==200){
        print("index exists")
        } 
else{   
        print("index doesn't exists")
        }
```